# unix throws error "sh: mntroot: not found" when doing sshpass with @host command, how to solve this?

Tags: linux, ssh, reboot, sshpass

My requirement : i want to pass some commands with sshpass command.
ex 1:

```
sshpass -p 'sshpass' ssh -oKexAlgorithms******* user@host touch /mnt/us/pass
```

above sshpass example works perfectly.

ex 2:

```
sshpass -p 'sshpass' ssh -oKexAlgorithms******* user@host mntroot rw
```

in above example, in host i have to give `mntroot rw` to enable read write permission for the logged user. this command not works when i pass with sshpass command and it throws `sh: mntroot: not found` error but it works perfectly in host when i logged in and entered it manually.

please help me on this.

Comment: Does it work with the full path of `mntroot`?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to call `mntroot` with the full path.

Interactive shells and non-interactive shells use different initialization files. That may be the reason. When you log in to the system you obviously have a different `PATH` value.